# How start method of Thread class create a new stack and execute run method

Tags: java, multithreading

Can some body help me to understand my below questions:-

1. When new stack is created? On executing `Thread t=new Thread()` or `t.start()`
2. How `start()` method calls implemented `run()`?
3. Can we assign memory to each thread like JVM? If NO, how JVM will modify stack memory of running thread.

Comment: I like the question, but, is this a homework?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Stack is created while the Start() method is called as till then the required info to create 
   the stack is not available.
2. The Thread class you call has this coded behind that calls run within its start method. 
   [In fact it is the Start() method that actually creates a new thread (not Thread class but the 
   real process thrad) and calls run() in the new thread. for eg: if you call run() instead of start
   () in your runnable class. No new thread will be created.]
3. No. We cant assign Specific amount of memory to a thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.htmlhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> A thread is a thread of execution in a program. The Java Virtual Machine allows an application to have multiple threads of execution running concurrently.
>
> Every thread has a priority. Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority. Each thread may or may not also be marked as a daemon. When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and is a daemon thread if and only if the creating thread is a daemon.
>
> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:

1. The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
2. All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

Now, to your questions.

- **When [is a] new stack is created? On executing Thread t=new Thread() or t.start()?**

A new thread is created by the constructor.  It is run with the start method.

- **How [does] start() method calls implemented run()?**

From the source code of [Thread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java):

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
         target.run();
    }
 }
```

- **Can we assign memory to each thread like JVM? If No, how JVM will modify stack memory of running thread.**

No, you cannot assign memory to each thread.  The operating system (Windows, Unix, OS X) controls how threads are created and destroyed.  The JVM has access to every thread through a string identifier.

You can read the [Thread source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java) for more information about the Thread class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am curious to know how start0() method of Thread class calls run() method

Comment: @Tathagat - it doesn't call the run() method. It calls whatever OS API is required to start a new thread, passing the run() function pointer.  The OS allocates the thread stack, loads the new stack with a top-of-stack frame, sets up internal control blocks etc. so that the thread state looks just like it has run before and has been interrupted.  It can then just schedule the new thread like any other and, when it wishes, make it run by interrupt-returning to it.